# How do I tell Qt5 applications which platform plugin to use?

Tags: plugins, qt5

My embedded target is running Linux and has two valid platform plugins: eglfs and linuxfb. By default, all my qt applications try to load eglfs(and fail for some reason). How can I make them try linuxfb?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By appending "-platform linuxfb" to the command line you are using to invoke the Qt5 application. Ex "./myqt5app -platform linuxfb". But linuxfb is broken as of Qt5.0.1 and will segfault.

To debug plugin issues - you can do "export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1" and check the logs printed.